# Transform Properies in CSS

Tags: css, css-transforms

I want to rotate an image when i hover on it.I use the follwing code to rotate.Bui it doesn't works....

```
#header #scn:hover{transform:rotate(45deg)};
```

It doesn't works for me.I am using Firefox 4.

Is there any way to perform transform and shadow effects in IE8.

Comment: Does **-moz-transform** work for you?

Comment: For Detailed knowledge on **CSS Transform** read this Article with running Demo [CSS Transform Property](http://www.kingofdevelopers.com/css-tips-and-tricks/css3-transform-property.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a prefix for every rendering engine. For Firefox the prefix is `-moz-`.

To rotate an image in all supported browsers use:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

For text shadows in IE8 you can use [Shadow Filter (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Plus there is CSS transforms workaround for Internet Explorer:
[cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/).